# AWS S3 TransferListener receive duplicated id of COMPLETED

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I downloaded S3TransferUtilitySample from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples. Then add the following code in it's UploadActivity for test:

```
    private void uploadFiles() {
        File dir = new File("/storage/sdcard0/DCIM");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for(File file : files) {
            uploadAFile(file);
        }
    }

    private void uploadAFile(File file) {
        if(file.isDirectory() || !file.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, file.getName(), file);
        observer.setTransferListener(new UploadListener());
    }
```

and my UploadListener looks like this:

```
private class UploadListener implements TransferListener {

        // Simply updates the UI list when notified.
        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during upload: " + id, e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onProgressChanged: %d, total: %d, current: %d",
                    id, bytesTotal, bytesCurrent));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState newState) {
            if(newState == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "file transfer completed:" + id);
            }
        }
    }
```

the uploadFiles() is called in some Button Click listener. Then I got the follow log:

```
file transfer completed:21
file transfer completed:26
file transfer completed:44
file transfer completed:44
file transfer completed:46
file transfer completed:46
file transfer completed:47
file transfer completed:47
file transfer completed:48
file transfer completed:48
```

You see, some of the ids are duplicated! That's wired! Do you know what's the problem? Help me.
(Note: I need using the id to do some more things once it is completed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the setup of the sample app. It has a list view that tracks transfer progress. It attaches a listener to each in progress transfers when the page loads. And you register one, same UploadListener. It looks like yours is triggered twice, but actually one comes from list view. Hope that explains.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. I have a second question [Android upload multiple files to AWS S3 failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640372/android-upload-multiple-files-to-aws-s3-failed). It's the same code, but different problem. Can you take a look at it also, please.