# Android upload multiple files to AWS S3 failed

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I downloaded S3TransferUtilitySample from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples. Start S3TransferUtility | Manage uploads | Upload an image
choose an image(my test image is a file about 23M). Then it start to transfer . This is the log:

```
    05-25 21:57:18.527  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/TransferSerivce﹕ Starting Transfer Service
    05-25 21:57:18.619  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/TransferSerivce﹕ Network connected: true
    05-25 21:57:18.619  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onStateChanged: 1, IN_PROGRESS
    05-25 21:57:18.619  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onStateChanged: 1, IN_PROGRESS
    05-25 21:57:18.619  15463-15570/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/TransferSerivce﹕ Loading transfers from database
    05-25 21:57:18.631  15463-15570/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/TransferSerivce﹕ 0 transfers are loaded from database
    05-25 21:57:19.323  15463-15571/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 202K, 6% free 5004K/5280K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
    05-25 21:57:19.975  15463-15571/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadTask﹕ multipart upload 1 in 5 parts.
    05-25 21:57:19.983  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 0
    05-25 21:57:20.007  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 0
    05-25 21:57:20.703  15463-15587/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 12% free 5103K/5744K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
    05-25 21:57:21.019  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 696320
    05-25 21:57:21.019  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 696320
    05-25 21:57:23.847  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 3276800
    05-25 21:57:23.851  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 3276800
    05-25 21:57:25.199  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 3751936
    05-25 21:57:25.199  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 3751936
    05-25 21:57:25.635  15463-15588/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 676K, 13% free 5128K/5876K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
    05-25 21:57:28.195  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 4423680
    05-25 21:57:28.199  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 4423680
    05-25 21:57:29.223  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 4620288
    05-25 21:57:29.231  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 4620288
    05-25 21:57:29.883      517-532/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{532611c0 u0 com.artisanstate.photobooks/com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService}
    05-25 21:57:33.307  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 5029888
    05-25 21:57:33.315  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 5029888
    05-25 21:57:34.435  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 5693440
    05-25 21:57:34.439  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 5693440
    05-25 21:57:36.427  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 5890048
    05-25 21:57:36.439  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 5890048
    05-25 21:57:37.619  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 6078464
    05-25 21:57:37.635  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 6078464
    05-25 21:57:39.107  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 6275072
    05-25 21:57:39.115  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 6275072
    05-25 21:57:40.539  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 6504448
    05-25 21:57:40.543  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 6504448
    05-25 21:57:42.011  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 6889472
    05-25 21:57:42.019  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 6889472
    05-25 21:57:43.503  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 7086080
    05-25 21:57:43.507  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 7086080
    05-25 21:57:45.999  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 7307264
    05-25 21:57:46.007  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 7307264
    05-25 21:57:47.503  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 7716864
    05-25 21:57:47.503  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 7716864
    05-25 21:57:51.139  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 7970816
    05-25 21:57:51.143  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 7970816
    05-25 21:57:55.495  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 8617984
    05-25 21:57:55.499  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 8617984
    05-25 21:57:57.799  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 8806400
    05-25 21:57:57.799  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 8806400
    05-25 21:57:59.507  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 9224192
    05-25 21:57:59.507  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 9224192
    05-25 21:58:02.007  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 9420800
    05-25 21:58:02.007  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 9420800
    05-25 21:58:04.775  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 9863168
    05-25 21:58:04.775  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 9863168
    05-25 21:58:07.519  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10248192
    05-25 21:58:07.523  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10248192
    05-25 21:58:09.283  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10444800
    05-25 21:58:09.287  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10444800
    05-25 21:58:11.187  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10633216
    05-25 21:58:11.187  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10633216
    05-25 21:58:13.095  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10756096
    05-25 21:58:13.103  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10756096
    05-25 21:58:15.319  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10944512
    05-25 21:58:15.323  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 10944512
    05-25 21:58:17.883  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11141120
    05-25 21:58:17.883  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11141120
    05-25 21:58:20.759  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11329536
    05-25 21:58:20.759  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11329536
    05-25 21:58:22.855  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11553747
    05-25 21:58:22.855  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11553747
    05-25 21:58:24.311  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11561939
    05-25 21:58:24.315  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11561939
    05-25 21:58:26.431  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11815891
    05-25 21:58:26.435  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 11815891
    05-25 21:58:27.495  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 12004307
    05-25 21:58:27.503  15463-15463/com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility D/UploadActivity﹕ onProgressChanged: 1, total: 23669715, current: 12004307
```

Then there are no more logs and the progress stop for ever!

After I download and debug with the [sdk source code] (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/). I found the program block in UrlHttpClient.java infinitely:

```
private void write(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 8];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        os.write(buf, 0, len); //block at this line!
    }
}
```

BTW the sdk version I use is 2.1.17.
Any friends can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:
- listener is unregistered. The sample app unregisters listeners when the upload activity pauses so as to prevent memory leak. I don't have the code and don't know your use case. But please make sure listener is still registered.
- Earlier SDK version has issue of keeping listeners alive. Please use the latest version v2.2.14 (or 2.2.13 if you experience NPE).

Comment: I updated the question, can you help to look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: which version of the SDK are you using? The latest one is v2.2.17.

Comment: do you log all state changes?

Comment: I simplify my question and append the log. I hope that can help to fix the problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The sample app registers listeners to in progress transfers when activity starts and unregisters them when activity stops. Not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: No, I didn't stop the activity. I used to debug your SDK source code. The program block in UrlHttpClient.java(I mention in my question ). That's why there is no new progress change. Note: this issue is NOT 100% reproducibility. The file is more than 20M, and I upload over a NOT very stable network(from China to  Oregon).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "block at this line". How do you know it's blocked there? Bad network should eventually fail the upload. If there isn't a reliable way to reproduce the issue, I am afraid that I can't help.

Comment: I add your SDK source code to the demo project, and add two different log just before and after the line os.write(buf, 0, len); Every time the issue occurred, I check the log, I can find the log before the line but without the log after the line.

Comment: That line writes data to output stream (network). If the network is bad, then this operation may take a while or fail in the worst case. I see no reason it will block forever. What's your device? Have you tried it on different devices/platforms?

Comment: All right. I will try to solve it by myself. Thank you all the same. :)